# 64-bit Linux virtual machine guest on a 32-bit host

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to find a way to use a 64-bit Linux virtual machine (I'd like to use Ubuntu 16.10-amd64 ISO from Ubuntu official website) through Oracle VirtualBox on my laptop. My laptop has Windows 8 32-bit installed, but my CPU is x64 based, so as far as I know I could replace 32-bit OS with a 64-bit OS, and there shouldn't be any issue with a 64-bit Linux virtual machine. Assuming that I can't change from a 32-bit OS to 64-bit OS, is there a way to run a 64-bit Linux virtual machine guest on a 32-bit OS host?

I've tried the steps from [Run 64bit OS in Virtual Box from 32bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21902/run-64bit-os-in-virtual-box-from-32bit-ubuntu), but while installing I get this error:

```
kernel panic not syncing fatal exception in interrupt
```

Comment: "is there a way to run 64bit linux virtualmachine on a 32bit os host? " only when your bios supports hardware virtualization (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host ) See the link for some more pointers you will need to check and configure "kernel panic not syncing fatal exception in interrupt" has to do with memory so probably is related to not being able to use a 64bit OS inside a 32bit system.   I would install a 64bit OS as your main ;-)

Comment: My bios supports hardware virtualization and it's enabled. I should be able to "run 64bit linux virtual machine on a 32bit os host" right? I can't understand what's wrong because i've already read http://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host and i fulfill all the requirements (i don't get the link's error).